# Jmeter - Running a HTTP Request once to store a key to be used in multiple threads

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to build a JMeter script that executes one HTTP Request to get a key, it then stores that key.

It then moves into another Threadgroup which loads tests an API but using that stored key, the reason for this is not to request the key hundreds of times as this is not what we are testing.

Any help is hugely appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use setproperty() in first thread group and save the key as a property and then fetch the key using get property in the second thread group.

${key}- Variable from regular expression holding secret key.

Setproperty Ex:-`${__setProperty(sec_key,${key})}`...Used JSR2223 Post processor to set property

Getproperty Ex:-`${__property(sec_key)}`...Use wherever it is required to pass the key

Also, check "Run thread group consecutively" option in Test Plan.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following approaches:

1. In [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) you can execute the HTTP request once and save the key into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and then access the value via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) where required
2. There is [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](http://Inter-Thread%20Communication) which can be used for passing data between threads even if they reside in different Thread Groups. See [SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx) test plan for details. You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).